# Text pasted into AS3 text field while .FLA limited to 246 lines, can this be increased?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In the Flash developer environment when I try and paste text in a text field it cuts the text off at about 246 lines.  I need about 3 times that.  When I publish the SWF the user can paste any amount of text in a text input field with no problem, so this really doesn't make sense to me.

The text is just the lyrics, translation, and vocabulary for a children's song.  I'm pretty sure I did something with more then 10 times this amount of text in AS2.

Does anyone3 know how to raise this limit or know a work around?

http://dontrimusic.blogspot.com/2015/01/elephant-song.html

Comment: I don't know what's your problem because the text field in your example is read only. Did you tried a TextArea component ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the text into the file before it is published, it is not for the user to enter.  If it is published the user has no problem entering the amount of text in an input field. I could have the user copy and paste the text themselves, or load an external text file but I really don't think that should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

if you want change text you can use static or dynamic text... if you want change content dynamical from code you need dynamic text... and if you want that user select your text you can turn on selectable property